# Can I modify expo push notification title/body before showing the notification?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-notifications

I'm using expo notification service.

I would like to send keys from backend, e.g.
{
title: "TITLE_KEY",
body: "BODY_KEY"
}

then translate it when it comes on the mobile side (based on the key), before showing it, so user would not see the key on notification, just the translated text...

So the question is how could I modify notification before showing it to the user?